# Best practice for AJAX/jQuery adding to a form and updating a list on the same page

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json

I am working on a page that has a form that puts data into one table, and also a list of items that come from that table.

I want to show the newest items on top of the list after the form is added.

Rigth now, the form makes an AJAX call, I get the data, send it back to jQuery in case of success, than I loop through the data.

But here I am confused about how to display the data.  If I use the append function, it will append to the bottom (I need it to go on top of the list). If I completely replace the list and repopulate it, is that the better solution? Seems heavy-handed.

What is the best pattern here to accomplish what I am trying to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

jQuery has a `prepend()` function which is essentially the opposite of `append()`; rather than adding to the bottom, it adds to the top. From the information you've given that should work for your particular use.

Comment: +1 if your primary problem is the location of the elements, this is definitely the way to go.

Comment: Prepend makes sense, but I am also concerned about n number of elements being added in a very short time span. Do people generally do this by just prepending last item? Or repopulating the whole list?

Comment: i would say . .prepend() .. repopulating the list may take a while on many items.

Comment: @Genadinik It depends on the number of items in the entire list, the number of items you need to add, and the amount of processing you're doing with the response data from the AJAX. If you need to do a lot of checking to find out which items -do- need to be added to the list (unlikely if they're already ordered), then it may be more efficient to simply rebuild the list every time. However, only worry about efficiency when you need to - if it's far too slow, worry about making it faster. I wouldn't waste time on a potentially neglibible performance improvement though.

Comment: Thanks guys - so if I want to wipe out the list and then rebuild it, what is the function to wipe out the div in jQuery and rebuild it anew?

Comment: @Genadinik You can just replace the innerHTML of the div using the `.html()` function of jQuery. Something like: `$(selector for your div).html(html for the list inside the div);`

Answer (score 2):

Try .prepend() instead of append();

[jquery site .prepend()](http://api.jquery.com/prepend/)

I hope it helps.